# QML MouseArea: how to propagate mouse events to other mouse areas?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a complex dialog that contains lots of controls in complex layouts. I need to add a cursor marker: vertical line which is drawn above this dialog and should follow the mouse cursor. 
I do not understand how to implement this.
Simplified sample code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: 50
        text: "Button"
        highlighted:  hovered
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: cursorMarker
        width: 1
        color: "black"
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onPositionChanged: {
            cursorMarker.x = mouse.x
        }

    }
}
```

In this sample, MouseArea placed above the button and intercepts all mouse messages. So the button is not highlighted when the mouse cursor moved above it. In case when MouseArea placed below the button then the cursor marker is not positioned correctly when mouse moved over the button.
But I need both: the cursor marker is positioned correctly above the whole dialog and the button working correctly.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Reading [propagateComposedEvents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop) I think it is not possible, since the propagation is only done for the clicked, doubleClicked and pressAndHold events

Comment: Maybe there is another way to implement this functionality, without event propagation.

Comment: Possibly you can get somewhere by setting the `cursorShape` to a normal mouse pointer with the vertical line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480

property int mousePosX : 0
property int mousePosY : 0

Button {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 100
    height: 50
    text: "Button"
    // Test if the mouse is within the Button
    highlighted:  mousePosX > x && mousePosX > y && mousePosX < x + width && mousePosY < y + height
}

Rectangle {
    id: cursorMarker
    x: mousePosX
    width: 1
    color: "black"
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
}

MouseArea {
    id: mouse
    anchors.fill: parent
    hoverEnabled: true

    onPositionChanged: {
        mousePosX = mouse.x
        mousePosY = mouse.y
    }
}
}
```

I suggest the following (Not exactly what you are asking, but another approach to implement the same) :

1. Store the mouse pos in some vars.
2. Then check if current mouse pos is within the button objects (by seeing if it lies within the bounding box of that button)

Comment: It looks like a workaround, but it seems this is the only solution. And this solution is very inconvenient: actually I have many controls inside this dialog.